# Is there a way for a value from a config file to contain empty lines?

Tags: python

I am using ConfigParser and I want to be able to get a text variable that has empty lines.
For example my config file looks like

```
[config]
text = hello

    goodbye
```

but when I display text it is

```
hello
goodbye
```

It ignores the empty line. I am wondering if there is a way to add a \n or something so it puts a blank empty line there

**EDIT:**I tried parser = SafeConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)

I tried placing \n in the config file, but that is just read as text.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There may be another way to do the same without having to depend on ConfigParser (e.g. adding a separator of some sort and replacing it with a newline on your program code)

Comment: I shouldn't have to do that when reading from a simple text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get interface provides substitutions that can be used for a suboptimal work around to the parser's strict handling of new lines:

```
> cat test.cfg 
[test] 
test=one%(nl)stwo%(nl)sthree

> cat test.py 
import ConfigParser
c = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
c.read('test.cfg')
print c.get('test','test', vars={"nl":"\n\n"})

> python test.py 
one

two

three
```

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is the escape code for a newline.  Try using those instead.

Comment: [config]
    text = hello
        \n    
        goodbye

Is displayed as
    hello
    \n
    goodbye

Comment: \n is preserved as a character string by ConfigParser

Comment: So I see... http://pypi.python.org/pypi/configobj/ might be a good alternative then.  I think Python 3's ConfigParser introduces options to fix this, as well.